# javascript callback is called twice in an impossible invocation

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

I built a TS, MongoDB Client wrapper. for some reason when I call the function that gets the connection, its callback is called twice.

There are 2 calls in total to the get() function, 1 before the export as you can see and another from a mocha test.

I am pretty new to TS and JS in general, but this seems a bit off.

> ```
>     import {Db, MongoClient} from "mongodb";
>     import {MongoConfig} from '../config/config'
>     class DbClient {
>         private cachedDb : Db = null;
>         private async connectToDatabase() {
>             console.log('=> connect to database');
>             let connectionString : string = "mongodb://" + MongoConfig.host + ":" + MongoConfig.port;
>             return MongoClient.connect(connectionString)
>                 .then(db => {
>                     console.log('=> connected to database');
>                     this.cachedDb = db.db(MongoConfig.database);
>                     return this.cachedDb;
>                 });
>         }
>         public async get() {
>             if (this.cachedDb) {
>                 console.log('=> using cached database instance');
>                 return Promise.resolve(this.cachedDb);
>             }else{
>                 return this.connectToDatabase();
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     let client = new DbClient();
>     client.get();
>     export = client;
> ```

where the console output is:

> ```
> => connect to database
> => connected to database
> => connected to database
> ```

Any particular reason this is misbehaving?

Comment: Side note: there's a race condition where `get` could be called multiple times before `this.cachedDb` is set which would lead to multiple connections/instance of `Db` being created. This can be avoided by assigning the promise of `connectToDatabase` to a private property then returning that promise in `get` (it should probably handle failures some way though).

Comment: Your Promise logic is flawed. in addition to what David suggests, the `get()` method returns a Promise wrapped in a promise or a resolved promise (`this.cachedDb`) wrapped in a promise. But then don't use either. You return from the promise from `MongoClient.connect()` but never use it (other then returning from `get`). Finally, you use then on the promise and return a a value that never get's used. Perhaps you should review the very simple design in the [Mongo Guides](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/reference/ecmascriptnext/connecting/)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I don't see any promises wrapped in a promise (promises that return a promise) in that code. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @David - `connectToDatabase()` is async and returns a Promise object, that Promise object is returned directly by `get()`, also an async function which returns a Promise wrapped in a Promise.

Comment: @Gleeb - check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/randycasburn/6fe40c1b935ee1ac5beba32dbd819371) It is your class written in a much cleaner way.

Comment: @RandyCasburn ah yeah, I missed the `async` keywords on the methods. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for replying with a code review on these promises, I am used to Scala and this shit just can't happen there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are 2 calls in total to the get() function, 1 before the export as you can see and another from a mocha test.

I suspect the output has an additional `=> connect to database`. As I said in the comments: There's a "race condition" where `get()` could be called multiple times before `this.cachedDb` is set which would lead to multiple connections/instances of Db being created.

For example:

```
const a = client.get();
const b = client.get();

// then
a.then(resultA => {
    b.then(resultB => {
        console.log(resultA !== resultB); // true
    });
});
```

**Solution**

The problem can be fixed by storing the promise as the cached value (also, no need to have the `async` keyword on the methods as Randy pointed out, as there's no values being awaited in any of the methods so you can just return the promises):

```
import {Db, MongoClient} from "mongodb";
import {MongoConfig} from '../config/config'

class DbClient {
    private cachedGet: Promise<Db> | undefined;

    private connectToDatabase() {
        console.log('=> connect to database');
        const connectionString = `mongodb://${MongoConfig.host}:${MongoConfig.port}`;
        return MongoClient.connect(connectionString);
    }

    get() {
        if (!this.cachedGet) {
            this.cachedGet = this.connectToDatabase();

            // clear the cached promise on failure so that if a caller
            // calls this again, it will try to reconnect
            this.cachedGet.catch(() => {
                this.cachedGet = undefined;
            });
        }

        return this.cachedGet;
    }
}

let client = new DbClient();
client.get();
export = client;
```

Note: I'm not sure about the best way of using MongoDB (I've never used it), but I suspect connections should not be so long lived as to be cached like this (or should probably only be cached for a short time and then disconnected). You'll need to investigate that though.

Comment: I used your code snippet thank you it's actually very concise and correct.
About the long lived session, I used this guide as a basis for my code (as I am building for Lambda).
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda/

Comment: @Gleeb ok, cool. As long as it's what they recommend. I wonder if you need to deal with reconnecting on unexpected disconnections, but perhaps that's all handled internally. I feel like they would have mentioned that if you needed to. Also, I see where you got your original code from!